# How to increase polling speed of data from external ADC (controller and ADC has SPI interface) without any external interrupt?

Tags: polling, spi, adc

I have an an external ADC which has capability to sample data at 40 Ksps and controller needs to poll the data from ADC. I am unable to get enough sampling rate by keep on calling it from `while (1)` loop, i.e nearly 8 Ksps what I am getting. It has no external pin to notify controller about data ready.

1) How to make it fast enough to reach up to that sampling rate?

2) Since I am sampling it at that rate, I need to transfer data on USB simultaneously so, how should I implement the buffering scheme to have minimum delay between consecutive data packet?

FYI:
My SYSCLK :168 MHz
SPI Clock: 10.5 MHz
controller: STM32F4

Comment: What OS? What kind of drivers do you use (user space / kernel space)? And where is your code in question?

Comment: Nucleo-144 board STM32F429 controller with STM32 HAL drivers code is generated using cubeMx